# Can CloudTrail Log SQS ReveiceMessage and SendMessage Events in Event History?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudtrail

I have CloudTrail logging my SQS queue's events, but the only SQS related events I see are CreateQueue and DeleteQueue. I am trying to have CloudTrail log ReceiveMessage and SendMessage SQS events as well. From my research, I am find both answers that it is possible and that it is not possible to have CloudTrail log ReceiveMessage and SendMessage events in the event history, so I am confused which answer is correct. Can anyone clarify this and if it is possible explain how to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible since [SQS data events are not recored in CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html#logging-data-events).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible since November 16, 2023.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/amazon-sqs-support-logging-data-events-aws-cloudtrail/

Note: `messageBody` (and likely other fields set by user) are logged as `HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS` string, which was a dealbreaker in my case.